# Start WPF application on computer startup

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, startup, autostart

I have a WPF application that I would like to be launched anytime the computer starts **NOT** when a user logs in. I know I can place the .exe in the startup folder, but I don't want that since a user has to login for that to be launched. I cannot use a Windows service, it's not an option for me.

Is there a way to start up an application once the PC starts up(or reboots), even before a user logs in? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the Task Scheduler? In Windows 7, there's a "Security options" section where you can set an option for a task to run whether a user is logged on or not. You can specify an executable file, and it'll start when Windows starts up.

*(This won't scale though, if you're looking for an option when a user installs your software. For that, a service is the* correct *way to go... you may need to elaborate in your question why exactly you **can't** use a service.)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds very interesting and a viable option. Any idea if this works with Windows XP? Can I use a script to create a task on a PC if the currently logged in user permits it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run an application without a user login. The only thing you can run is a [Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9.aspx), which I'm guessing from your question being about WPF that this is not what you want.